# Linux: all commands return Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I was messing around with my Path variables and after putting the following 3 commands, every shell command I execute would return a Fatal Python error:

> export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:z3/bin
>
> export PATH=$PATH:z3/bin
>
> export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7

Error message:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/**init**.py", line 123
>       raise CodecRegistryError,\
>                               ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax Aborted

Does anyone how can I fix this? I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/640492/225111) suggests that by changing `PYTHONPATH` you may be cause the active Python to mistakenly load a _different_ version's files. Also, please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Have you try dpkg-reconfigure locales as root?